# How to create a JCA adapter in Jakarta EE 9?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jca, resource-adapter

How to create or build a new **JCA resource adapter (.rar)** to connect to a new data store (in-memory data grid) system and which is compliant to the **Jakarta EE 9 specifications** to be able to use on the micorservices space .